# which functional module is used to retrieve data from a table based on certain conditions?

Tags: abap

In ABAP which functional module is used to retrieve data from a table based on certain conditions?

Comment: To vague a question. Almost every function module accesses tables based on conditional arguments.

Comment: In case somebody else is wondering: No - a function module will still be a function module without accessing the database.
What the question describes is a `query` and not a `function module`.

Answer (score 11):

Well, if you're writing ABAP, you just write your OpenSQL statement(s) directly in code. OpenSQL is a first-class part of the ABAP language.

But if you are asking how to read a table using a function module...

You can make arbitrary table reads using the RFC_READ_TABLE function module. Happily it's RFC-enabled. It allows you to pass in the 'where' clause directly.

The only caveat is that the data is returned in a table structure only 512 characters wide. If you read from a table wider than that, data will be truncated. Also, it is a flat field, so you need to parse out each table column/field manually.

So, not particularly user friendly, but useful if you have no other options.

It's available in all releases back to 4.6C (probably even earlier).

Answer (score 3):

Normally, you write it using ABAP's OPEN SQL statements. This is very similar to normal SQL statements. It is very easy to write them than to use a Function Module unless you want to call the Function Module on a remote system (Remote Function Call, which can be called from an SAP or NON-SAP system).

This is how it looks like:

```
TYPES:
  BEGIN OF ty_material,
    matnr TYPE mara-matnr,
    attyp TYPE mara-attyp,
  END OF ty_material.

DATA:
  gt_material TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_material,
  gs_material LIKE LINE OF gt_material.

*--This is an OPENSQL statement--*
SELECT matnr
       attyp
  INTO TABLE gt_material
  FROM mara
 WHERE attyp BETWEEN ('01' AND '03').

LOOP AT gt_material
  INTO gs_material.

  WRITE: / gs_material-matnr, gs_material-attyp.
  CLEAR gs_material.
ENDLOOP.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below FMs:

```
RS_VARIANT_CONTENTS - Values of a variant returned in a table 

RS_VARIANT_EXISTS - Checks whether a variant exists for a report 

RS_VARIANT_TEXT - Returns short description of variant 

RS_VARIANT_VALUES_TECH_DATA - Reads variant parameters of a report
```

And also you can try this

```
SD_COND_T685_SELECT - to fetch the access sequence for the given condition type.

SD_T682I_SINGLE_READ - to fetch the condition tables.
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand the question, the question is not about downloading conditions.